# What is the most secure method of collecting bank and sort details via an online form

Tags: web-application

I want to create an online webform that records users; name, address, bank account and sortcode (UK). each entry will be copied locally and then deleted.

I have read so much about what I shouldn't do, the security implications etc, but I can't find what I **should** do.

I am prepared to use third party applications or services where needed. I looked into hushmail forms and google forms but they do not cater for validation of fields and discourage sensitive info storing.

Comment: The secure method of doing this is to find a way so that you can do what you need to do without collecting these data, why do you think you need to collect these data?

Comment: Collect as little as possible, you must use https, you should check your legal requirements to comply with pci-dss and the DPA.

Comment: You appear to have a very limited understanding of security.  This combined with the collection of personal data is a disaster waiting to happen. My advice: FORGET ABOUT creating your own, really, just FORGET IT.  Take your time, do some research, and find a third-party service that specialises in collecting and safely storing data (hint: look for buzz-words like PCI-DSS, ISO27001 ... i.e. companies that do more that just primitive https forms )  Then you just create a link to a form on someone else's server, and they take the responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question, but I will try to answer it as well as possible.  First, as has been mentioned in the comments, see if you can design around the problem.  That means see if you can find a way to make your application work without needing the account number or sort code information.

If that's not possible, see if you can find a third party who is able to store that information for you.  [Payment Tokenization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization_(data_security)) is your friend.  Let someone else deal with the security/liability.  Be aware you may still have some responsibility under any applicable laws.

If that isn't possible, then your last resort is to store the information yourself.  This is sub-optimal at best.  Make sure your application implements SSL properly.  Make sure that the data is properly encrypted while at rest.  Your application should be properly penetration tested.  Make sure your have proper security monitoring in place.  You should also have an incident response plan in place.  You will need to make sure you are compliant with any applicable legislation.